# Плагин множественной загрузки файлов на сервер?

Tags: jquery

Хочу разобраться в этом плагине: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API, впрочем не новый, я думаю многие сталкивались, в общем подключал я все файлики которые надо, инициализировал плагин, загружаю файлы а тут бац:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
```

Че это? Да! **html5** он самый!

Вопрос: А как быть если я не могу (или же не хочу) использовать **html5** в этом плагине, как быть?

**upd** 1. Ладно, извиняюсь, что-то я попутал, скорее всего проблема не с html5, а с путями, создал папку **uploads** в корне, аттрибут у тега такой:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/uploads/" multiple>
```

Пропбую файлы залить, а оно ругается на:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /uploads/ was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

В смысле такой мне приходит ответ.

Comment: что вас не устраивает? data-атрибуты? или атрибут `multiple`, который не все браузеры поддерживают? что именно?

Comment: то что плагин не срабатывает, да, здесь прописан url в data-url, коих в обычном html (тобишь не в html5) просто нету, вот не знаю как выкрутится, так как это сразу же ошибка (по поводу путей сохранения) в любом браузере.

Comment: аааай!!! Извиняюсь, сам виноват, там в uploads просто должен быть файл какой-нть скрипт php, который уже будет дальше обрабатывает все что пришло от клиента.